# centering the text in the flag

Tags: css

How can I center the text in the image below

I have this

```
.flag{ 
    background: url('flag.png') no-repeat;
    width:120px; 
height:120px; 
}
</style>

<div class="flag">WOW</div>
```

This is how its showing up currently
[image: wrong alignment of text]

Comment: Please tag your questions properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.flag{ 
    background: url('flag.png') no-repeat;
    width:120px; 
    height:120px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:120px;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
text-align: center;
line-height: 120px;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
.flag{ 
    background: url('flag.png') no-repeat;
    width:120px; 
    height:120px; 
    line-height:120px; /* same as height */
    text-align:center;
}
```